# PowerBI next row value to column base on unique column values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My data in powerbi is this:

| Order number | seconds |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 51 |
| 10 | 100 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 20 | 12 |
| 20 | 722 |
| 20 | 3 |
| 30 | 200 |
| 40 | 98 |
| 40 | 0 |
| 50 | 5 |
| 50 | 200 |
| 50 | 200 |

Based on the order number, I am trying to make a new column to get the next row's seconds.

The final result should be like this

| Order number | seconds | Next seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 51 | 100 |
| 10 | 100 | 2 |
| 10 | 2 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 'BLANK' |
| 20 | 12 | 722 |
| 20 | 722 | 3 |
| 20 | 3 | 'BLANK' |
| 30 | 200 | 'BLANK' |
| 40 | 98 | 0 |
| 40 | 0 | 'BLANK' |
| 50 | 5 | 200 |
| 50 | 200 | 200 |
| 50 | 200 | 'BLANK' |

Comment: Are there any other columns for the ordering like date/time column, or index column? If not, are the rows ordered as they are shown above?

Comment: Yes the rows are in order as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **PowerQuery**:

1. Right-click on the `Order number` column header and select `Group by...`. Set `New column name` to `Rows`, and `Operation` to `All rows`.
2. Add a new step with the following:

```
Table.TransformColumns(
    #"Grouped rows", // <-- update to match previous step's name
    {"Rows", each Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(_) & { List.RemoveFirstN([seconds] & {null}, 1) },
        Table.ColumnNames(_) & { "Next seconds" }
      )
    }
  )
```

3. Lastly, expand the `Rows` by click on the "split" arrows `↰↱`, select `seconds` and `Next seconds` without `Use original column name as prefix`.

---

Here is the full PQ script:

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjRQ0lEyNVSK1YGyDQ0MEBwjBBMiagRWYoRgmxshcYzBTGOwTqgxJiCOpQWCDRE2BVuLYMKUIzixAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Order number" = _t, seconds = _t]),
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Order number", Int64.Type}, {"seconds", Int64.Type}}, "en-US"),
  #"Grouped rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed column type", {"Order number"}, {{"Rows", each _, type nullable table[#"Order number" = nullable Int64.Type, seconds = nullable Int64.Type]}}),
  ShiftSecondsUp = Table.TransformColumns(
    #"Grouped rows",
    {"Rows", each Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(_) & { List.RemoveFirstN([seconds] & {null}, 1) },
        Table.ColumnNames(_) & { "Next seconds" }
      )
    }
  ),
  #"Expanded Rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ShiftSecondsUp, "Rows", {"seconds", "Next seconds"}, {"seconds", "Next seconds"})
in
  #"Expanded Rows"
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thanks for the help.